# Seeking an example of a procedure that uses row_count

Tags: mysql

I want to write a procedure that will handle the insert of data into 2 tables. If the insert should fail in either one then the whole procedure should fail. I've tried this many different ways and cannot get it to work. I've purposefully made my second insert fail but the data is inserted into the first table anyway.

I've tried to nest IF statements based on the rowcount but even though the data fails on the second insert, the data is still being inserted into the first table. I'm looking for a total number of 2 affected rows.

Can someone please show me how to handle multiple inserts and rollback if one of them fails? A short example would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using InnoDB tables (or other compatible engine) you can use the [Transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html) feature of MySQL that allows you to do exactly what you want.

- Basically you start the transaction
- do the queries checking for the result
- If every result is OK you call the CONMIT
- else you call the ROLLBACK to void all the queries within the transaction.

You can read and article about with examples [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3382171/Transactions-in-MySQL.htm).

HTH!

Comment: I should have mentioned it in my post but I made the assumption that everyone would know that I was already using transactions. The issue is that row_count returns a 1 for the first insert and I'm assuming a -1 for the second. Even though the transaction has started, the data is still inserted into the first table when the 2nd insert fails. I'm already testing the affected rows that should equal 2. if not rollback else commit.

Comment: And using transaction with innoDB tables isn't it rolling back the first query?

Comment: No SubniC, it's weird. I just noticed it tonight while working on a different part of the site. I'm using Innodb and have never ran into this before. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: What version of MySQL server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could try turning autocommit off.  It might be automatically committing your first insert even though you haven't explicitly committed the transaction that's been started:

`SET autocommit = 0;
START TRANSACTION
......`